# Facebook | Page Plugin iframe does not load when logged into Facebook

Tags: facebook, iframe, plugins

I have a problem with the [Page Plugin](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin) iframe from Facebook.

I tried multiple browsers, facebook user accounts and pages and the behaviour seems to be always the same:

**When the Facebook user is logged in, the timeline part of the frame will not load.**

To reproduce it:

1. open https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin
2. if there are no facebook sessions open the plugin opens fine (in the **preview pane** of the setup page, **opening the url** in a browser window, or **embeding** the provided iframe code)
3. if there is a logged in user in facebook in the same browser session, the timeline will NOT load

note: there are some scripts errors, but they seem to appear on both scenarios

facebook setup page

[image]

standalone url
[image]

Comment: Sounds like this issue: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/584988619248795/

Comment: looks very similar, @CBroe, thanks. "hopefully" it's a a bug and not something on my end

Comment: It is this, BUT they closed the bug, although it is still there. Bug is still there, but they do nothing :(